# 3 tables joins on One to many

Tags: mysql

Im having some troubles learning about joins, im working with 2 One-to-many relation ships:

In this case, i have novels with many chapters and many ratings

I need to get the novels information plus a count of chapters associated to each novel and an avarage of the ratings of each novel and im trying this:

```
SELECT n.id
     , n.nvl_title
     , COUNT(c.id) AS nvl_chapters
     , AVG(nr.rate_value) as nvl_rating
     , MAX(c.createdAt) AS nvl_last_update
  FROM novels n
  left 
  JOIN novels_ratings nr 
    ON nr.novel_id = n.id
  left 
  JOIN chapters c 
    ON c.nvl_id = n.id 
   AND c.chp_status = 'Active'
 WHERE n.nvl_status IN ("Active", "Finished") 
 GROUP 
    BY n.id;
```

Working only with the chapters the query seems to work very fine but if I add the line "left JOIN novels_ratings nr ON nr.novel_id = n.id" the chapters count increment to many ratings the novel have.

For example: A novel with 2 chapters and 2 rating returns 4 chapters in total.

Any help will be fully apreciated.

If there is something I miss to explain, please, let me know and i will try to clarify.

I'veen working with some ugly querys that do the job but as soon as the chapters table begin to have MANY registers I have been forced to learn more optical querys

**EDIT**

I have create a small database, enough to make some tests on the query:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `chapters` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nvl_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chp_title` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chp_status` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active',
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


INSERT INTO `chapters` (`id`, `nvl_id`, `chp_title`, `chp_status`, `createdAt`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'generic chapter 1', 'Active', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
(2, 1, 'generic chapter 2', 'Active', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');

CREATE TABLE `novels` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `nvl_title` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nvl_status` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Active'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;


INSERT INTO `novels` (`id`, `nvl_title`, `nvl_status`) VALUES
(1, 'generic novel', 'Active');

CREATE TABLE `novels_ratings` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `novel_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rate_value` int(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `novels_ratings` (`id`, `novel_id`, `rate_value`) VALUES
(1, 1, 3),
(2, 1, 4);

ALTER TABLE `chapters`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `novels`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `novels_ratings`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `chapters`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

ALTER TABLE `novels`
  MODIFY `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

ALTER TABLE `novels_ratings`
  MODIFY `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
COMMIT;
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to process both aggregations separately.

Comment: And you'll need a full join... that is not supported by MySQL [yet]. Can be done but the query will be ugly.

Comment: You can use this site to learn about joining;  [SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). This site explains Join methods with examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have seen many tutorials about joins but I cant find an answer about why if I made two joins, one to the chapters and the other to the ratings, why the chapters count ingrease to many items the novel have associated (chapters and ratings). belive me, write a question in stackoverflow is always the last thing I do afters hours trying by my self.

@The Impaler. How can I do exactly what you are mentioning?

Comment: @AndresPlazaMarqués There you go. I finally got the time to write the whole solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do this is here:

```
SELECT n.id, n.nvl_title,
       COUNT(c.id) AS nvl_chapters,
       (select AVG(nr.rate_value) from novels_ratings nr where nr.novel_id = n.id) as nvl_rating,
       MAX(c.createdAt) AS nvl_last_update
FROM novels n
left JOIN chapters c ON c.nvl_id = n.id AND c.chp_status = 'Active'
WHERE n.nvl_status IN ("Active", "Finished") 
GROUP BY n.id;
```

Very straightforward, and it should perform well too.

Comment: Hi @Marc Thanks for your answer, I have try this before and works, but Im worried about the thing that novel_ratings table could have hundreds of entries making that another  SELECT inside the query will slow down the query performance just as happended to me with the chapter table

Joins seems to work in a much efficient way and that's why my persistence to achieve this query with two joins (if possible)

Comment: If your table is indexed correctly, this should not be an inefficient query. But you can do a `join` in very similar fashion by querying a temp table and joining on that. Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete solution (finally). Since MySQL does not implement `FULL JOIN` the solution uses a `LEFT JOIN` paired with a `RIGHT JOIN` instead.

You can do:

```
with
r as (
  select n.id, avg(nr.rate_value) as nvl_rating
  from novels n
  join novels_ratings nr on nr.novel_id = n.id
  group by n.id
),
c as (
  select n.id, count(c.id) as nvl_chapters, max(c.createdAt) as nvl_last_update
  from novels n
  join chapters c on c.nvl_id = n.id and c.chp_status = 'Active' 
  group by n.id
)
select r.id, r.nvl_rating, c.*
from r
left join c on c.id = r.id
UNION ALL
select c.id, r.nvl_rating, c.*
from r
right join c on c.id = r.id
where r.id is null
```

Comment: Thank you very much @The Impaler, it look really interesting and useful, I'll do some testing on this query, share the results, and mark you as a correct answer if it does.